# Fix the color difference of website on Mac / PC?

Tags: css, web, platform-specific

The website is designed on a mac, but it shows a different color on a PC. I guess that this is something I have to ignore and follow the middle path, but is it possible to do something more drastic about it? Is there any way to target Mac browsers or PC browsers?

I found other similar topics but they were not concerning about colors.

What if I target User Agents? I read somewhere that it is a bad idea, but there was no explanation even I can only guess it. Normally I wouldn't try this, but in my case, colors were strictly chosen from the client, and insists on using them as they are. And as colors are very different I've no other choice.

Answer (score 0):

Every screen is different and will show the colors in a different bit. Contrast has a lot to do about now showing the #f0f0f0, and in some screens it is as beuetifull gray as can be.

There is nothing you can do about the colors. You just have to live with it.